# Flutter, Linux doesn't show up as device

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-desktop

I followed the steps here at [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/desktop). It didn't work. Linux is not showing when I run `flutter devices`. I'm running Linux Mint 19.3.
This is the output from `flutter doctor`

```sh
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] Connected device
 ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: try  master channel... do you have various versions of flutter ?

Comment: What do you get when executing `flutter emulators` on terminal ?

Comment: How can I switch to the master branch? I'm using the snap version. `Pixel_2_API_27 • Pixel 2 API 27 • Google • android` the output for `flutter emulators`

Comment: Note that the very first step in the setup section tells you to switch channels; it didn't work because you skipped a step: https://flutter.dev/desktop#set-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linux desktop development only works after the master release, go to the flutter root on terminal and run:

```
git checkout master && flutter doctor
```

after this you will see the linux on `flutter devices`

Comment: I'm using the snap version, so I don't think I can do that.

Comment: use 'flutter channel master' so

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

Select the "dev" channel like this:

```
flutter channel dev
```

Then upgrade flutter:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then enable the linux desktop option again:

```
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop

flutter devices
```

Then you should see output like below:

> Downloading package sky_engine...
> 5.6s Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                           25.9s
> Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...
> 8.8s Downloading linux-x64 tools...                                      8.1s
> Downloading linux-x64/font-subset tools...
> 7.1s 1 connected device:
>
> Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Linux